# After installing Ionic it says 'ionic' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm

First of all I installed it with command:

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

Then I tried installing in admin mode. I also tried `npm cache clear` then navigate to npm folder and remove it. Then restart cmd, restart computer but still same problem.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 but it's already solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the path to point the `ionic` global module's location.

You can do that by issuing the below command.

`set PATH=%PATH%;C:\users\[Logged_In_User_directory]/AppData/Roaming/npm;`

Once you execute the above command, your ionic cli will work fine.

Hope this helps!

Comment: U r a hero, man! :) Tks!