# Ionic installed locally but not able to run command

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, node-modules

I installed ionic locally instead of global with out giving -g option

But when I run command ionic start

It gives error
[image]

Comment: check this: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/local-installation/144138/6

Answer (score 0):

Frist try reinstalling it:

```
npm uninstall -g ionic
npm install -g @ionic/cli
```

Then if the error is still there, make sure you have the PATH variable set correctly! See more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46081657/15947768)

Also try to close and reopen the terminal.

Comment: thanks for your response , but I need this locally instead of global

Comment: i have not installed it globally, i just need it in local env in a specified folder

Comment: I understand, but the terminal won't recognize the command unless it has a PATH to it. See more about path variables here: https://www.tiagoporto.com/blog/environment-setting-tutorial-ionic-android-on-windows/